# Flex & nginx : Channel.Call.Failed

Tags: apache-flex, nginx, tomcat7, remoteobject, graniteds

I created a web application, here is the architecture :

- Tomcat7 deploy on Amazon EC2
- Granite DS
- nginx to redirect HTTPS throught the tomct7 port 8181
- Flex application that uses RemoteObject on a secure Channel.

Occasionaly, maybye when a request takes to long time, the execution of a RemoteObject in Flex triggers this error :

```
faultCode:Channel.Call.Failed faultString:'error' faultDetail:'NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP: Status 504'
```

But in the most time, the response of the Remote object is correct.

Could you tell me if Nginx could block something? Or if BlazeDs has a tomeout?Any clues?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

We've had this issue for a long time...problem is we haven't been able to find a repeatable way to force it to disconnect.

Here the most comprehensive list of things to try that i've been able to find:
http://www.bopit.in.th/2009/10/14/flex-channel-connect-failed-error-netconnection-call-failed-http-status-200/

We've tried a couple of those solutions and it seems like we're getting less client disconnects.

There also may be a problem with AVG's linkscanner hijacking the request as it leaves the browser, and then losing it somewhere.  We had one machine in our shop that would disconnect when using IE, and since uninstalling AVG, it's never happened on that machine again.

another thing you could check is the socket timeout: 
[NetConnection.Call.Failed happening sporadically in Flex3/Tomcat/BlazeDS/Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145065/netconnection-call-failed-happening-sporadically-in-flex3-tomcat-blazeds-spring)

and here is a thread on adobe forum about the issue:
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/552133